# How to prevent lerna from creating link of issues

Tags: lerna

If there are commits like `feat: [Org/Repo#123]` lerna(with `conventionalCommits:true` option) converts it to

`feat: [Org/Repo[#123](remoteOriginUrl/issues/123)]`

How to prevent lerna from creating auto github issue links?

Comment: I'll assume you use `--conventional-commits` and if so, the link is created by [conventional-changelog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conventional-changelog) npm package not by Lerna itself, that external dependencies has ways to change how the link are created

Comment: yes I was using conventional commits options. Thank you for your advice :)